# Mango plant twig growing downward then upwards

Tags: mango

There is a strange way of development in one of my mango trees. The new twig grow new leaves, but with the weight of leaves twig goes downward and then again upward. So its something like
[image]

The problem is tree not growing upward... the twigs are overlapping one an other and even touching the ground.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please explain what your question is? You are describing the situation quite nicely, but I am missing a clear question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience with Bahamian Yellow Elder (*Tecoma stans*) that I have in pots. I would post an image but yours illustrates what happened quite well. Each fall I prune them quite hard back so that there is no foliage, this is to reduce watering over the winter while they are in storage; less leaf area means less transpiration. They suffer no harm, resprout in the spring and away we go again. One of the three did what your picture shows, except that in my case there was one dominant leader (the top bud) that grew straight and strong, the other lower 4 buds did the curly thing.

So the question is why this happens. The lower buds were not in the shade of the leader since the foliage of *T. stans* is not that dense. I figure it is more a matter of root strength versus top growth vigour. The side shoots grow out hard and fast and become heavy while still soft, bend over, harden up and then grow normally upwards.

Whether this relates to your situation rather depends. Was there heavy pruning of the top to force out side shoots? Perhaps the natural dominant leader was accidentally broken when a fat bird landed on it. In any case I don't think there is anything to be concerned about that corrective pruning could not fix.

Comment: Brilliantly explained! Yeah looks like I mistakenly prune it wrongly :(. So, should I prune it again the outer shootouts?